# Kernel headers point to older kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, linux-headers

On my Ubuntu 18.04.1 system, I upgraded my linux kernel from `linux-image-4.15.0-123-generic` to `linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700-generic` to get a fix not present in 4.15. I followed the instructions [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/install-linux-kernel-4-17-ubuntu-18-04/):

```
cd /tmp/

wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_all.deb

wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/linux-modules-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb

wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb

wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

But it looks like the including the kernel headers in my program (for eg., `<sys/mman.h>`) still seem to include headers from the older kernel. 4.17 headers are installed in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700/` and I am currently logged in to the 4.17 kernel:

```
root@node-0:~/pmdk# uname -r
4.17.0-041700-generic
```

How can I check which header version the compiler (`gcc 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04`) uses? How do I make it point to kernel headers for 4.17?

Comment: FYI: I wouldn't call that an upgraded kernel, your old kernel was patched (security fixes back-ported to it), which you've replaced with a *testing* kernel that has had no security fixes applied to it.  I personally would call that a downgrade  (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two supported kernel options, GA=4.15, HWE=5.4 and I'd suggest sticking with one of them)

Comment: I'm not much concerned with that. I am working on a course project and the application I'm building requires 4.17 or later. The system is a temporary test system. I'll try upgrading to HWE